# Are unofficial Wiimotes a good alternative to official Nintendo ones?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

I'm looking for new Wiimotes, for the legacy Wii. My goal is to buy the 3rd and 4th Wiimotes for my console. These devices will be primarily used to play some games with children, like Mario, not high-paced games.

I can see [a lot of "compatible" devices](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=wiimote&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Awiimote) that are neither official nor built by Nintendo.

What is the quality of these alternative devices compared to the official ones?

Do these devices operate like an official one? Should I expect the same reactivity, precision, etc.?

I assume the global finish of the product may give a cheaper feeling, but I can live with that.

Comment: As always, you get what you pay for.  "Good idea" is subjective.  We deal with objectivity, as in, does the controller *work*.  I'd recommend re-wording your question to something a bit more objective.

Comment: Thanks @Frank for you advise. Sometimes hard to express question as English is not my mother tongue. I tried to be more precise in my words.

Comment: I think that's a better wording.  As a sidenote, I believe you missed a letter in your profile; your last line probably doesn't say what you want it to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These devices certainly can work, I've got a third party Wii remote with motion plus, and it does get recognized in game as such, however the build quality is lower. Not terribly so, but certain buttons don't feel quite right.

It comes down to the quality of the specific device and your personal willingness to put up with the specific quality issues, but generally speaking the quality difference is noticeable and I wouldn't particularly recommend them. FWIW, motion sensing actually seemed to work better than the physical buttons, which felt off. But only first party controllers can really guarantee (with warranty) a certain level off correct "feel".